# Convert Darknet Weights and cfg file to ONNX or Pytorch weight files

Tags: pytorch, object-detection, yolo, onnx, darknet

I have some pretrained darknet weights and config files used with a Yolov3 model.

I recently switched to Ultralytics to use Yolo v5. I don't really want to retrain, and a lot of the models relied on transfer learning from other .weight files.

I have looked online and found a github repo(s) that were promising, but have had no luck with them. Posts about this are from over a year ago.

i.e https://github.com/Tianxiaomo/pytorch-YOLOv4

I'm hoping that somoeone here may be able to help with this conversion?

Comment: It's mentioned in the readme how to convert model weights from darknet to onnx of the pytorch-yolov4 repo.